# How to check that at least one row complies to a condition (WHERE clause) in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

The task is to have a query returning 0 if no rows are going to be returned if the condition is applied and 1 if there are going to be more than 0 rows. Preferably this query should be faster than just querying the table with the condition and limiting the query with 1 row in result set.

Comment: It's not going to be any faster unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case 
        when exists (
            select * 
            from MyTable 
            where MyColumn = 23
        ) then 1 
        else 0 
    end as RowsExist
```

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HNS_MSG_RCV_0) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS RES;`

Not working: PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @AmebaSpugnosa Since you are using Oracle, not MySQL, you'll likely need to add `from dual` at the end of the query.